# Adding a wide enough textarea in a `tr` affects the calculation of `td` width?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-table

I have a DOM structure like the following:

```
<table class="playlist">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>TH1</th>
            <th width="53">TH2</th>
            <th width="53">TH3</th>
            <th width="53">TH4</th>
            <th width="53">TH5</th>
            <th width="53">TH6</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>TD1</td>
            <td>TD2</td>
            <td>TD3</td>
            <td>TD4</td>
            <td>TD5</td>
            <td>TD6</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="expansion">
            <td class="expansion" colspan="6">
                <div class="comment_wrapper">
                    <form>
                        <textarea style="width=482px" class="mini">x</textarea>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Related style rules are like:

```
table {
    width: 580px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}

.comment_wrapper {
height: 270px;
border: 1px red solid;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}

.comment_wrapper form textarea {
height: 70px;
width: 482px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
border: 1px red solid;
}
```

My problem is that whenever I added the second `tr`, width of table columns changed into a mess like the following in IE6/7.

[image]

When I comment out this `tr`, the column width restore.

Why does adding a `tr` affects column width? How can I avoid this effect?

**PS**
I've reproduced this problem on JSFiddle, and this is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/7mYY8/1/

Comment: Are you required to still support IE6?

Comment: @Jared Unfortunately, yes. IE6 users still make up quite a fraction of our site's users.

Comment: Looking at it in FF8 (I don't have access to IE6), I see that the first column is quite a bit wider than the rest, which are all uniform. Is this what you're after? And why aren't you using a class for the uniform widths instead of a `width` attribute?

Comment: @Jared Yes, that's what I want, though it doesn't works in IE6/7. I have edited the question and add a screenshot of the table from IE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have 6 columns 5 of which have a defined width.

The 1st column doesn't.  This means it has to be computed.  Sure you have the table width defined in CSS, but IE 6 isn't exactly the best thing.

Your best bet is going to be to explicitly define the width of all of your header columns.  Then give the table the css attribute of "table-layout: fixed".  This is going to enforce your widths for the entire rendering of the table.